# How to test if a private method eventually throws?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a class with only one public method: `run()`.

When I call `run()` it calls two other methods, where one of the methods eventually throws.

```
expect(await object.run()).toThrow(Error);

// run() -> this.handler() -> this.validate() -> this.getObject()
```

`this.getObject()` returns false, which in turn means `this.validate()` is false, and so one of the conditions inside `this.handler` fails, resulting in a throw.

The throw works as expected, but my current test does not pass.

Typically, how can one test that a private method, triggered eventually by a public method, throws?

Comment: Does `run` `try..catch` the exception? If not, the exception bubbles up and it is irrelevant where exactly it is being thrown. If `run` *does* catch the exception, then it's an internal implementation detail, and as far as the caller is concerned no exception was raised. And you don't test implementation details with unit tests.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether or not the private method throws (and you shouldn't test for that anyway), only that the public method throws. But the proper method to do that in jest is [`await expect(object.run()).rejects.toThrow();`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#rejects).

Comment: See how how to expect exceptions: https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror. The way you're writing it, jest has no way to catch the exception itself.

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous